# How to create a static state model in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I have two "Systems", denote `System1` and `System2`.
I want each system to have a state from a finite number of states (`On` or `Off` to be precise)
I also want `System1` to be able to change the state of `System2` from `On` to `Off`.
I am struggling to understand where I should use predicates, functions, and what I should assign to fields? I have found information on dynamic models, but I do not want to introduce time.
How do I model that System1 can switch the state of System2?

Many thanks

```
abstract sig System{ state: states}
one sig System1 extends System{
switch: System2 -> states
}
one sig System2 extends System{}
abstract sig states{}
one sig On,Off extends states{}

run{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to model the idea that System2 (for example) has a state that changes, that means you will need to somehow represent different states at different times. So some notion of time or state is unavoidable.